# Dirac equation from a vierbein operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, operators, dirac-equation

Klein-Gordon equation can be derived straightforwardly by getting the mass-energy relation from special relativity in tensorial form, $$\eta^{\mu\nu}p_{\mu}p_{\nu} = m^2c^2$$
and promoting the variables to operators.
Dirac's motivation to find its equation was to find a first order equation instead of second order, so my idea was:
Can't we write the mass-energy relation using vierbeins? We get $$e^{\mu}p_{\mu} = \pm mc$$ and then we promote the variables to operators and get a first order equation for the wavefunction! If there isn't nothing wrong with my logic, what would be the vierbein operator? How is this connected to the Dirac equation?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform thanks man. But I'm still troubled about how the gamma matrices emerge from the formalism i wrote. Are they a correct quantization of the vierbein?

Comment: hint: [Dirac gamma matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices). The Dirac equatio is $\gamma^\mu p_\mu\psi=m\psi$. Compare this to your second equation.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Thanks for the fast reply, and i have to mention that i spotted the similarity earlier.But if the vierbein operators are the gamma matrices, how can one arrive at Klein-Gordon equation just with the vierbein formalism? And how do one derive that the gamma matrices don't commute and, therefore, are matrices just with the formalism i wrote? I'm interested on the concept of the thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer.** A vierbein is a choice of a preferred inertial frame at a particular spacetime point. That is, it is a collection of *four* *four*-vectors. I insist on the two *four*s in the previous sentence. In fully expanded index notation, you’d write it as $e^\mu_\alpha$: *sixteen* components! So, on the surface, your formula doesn’t make sense because it has vectors on the left and scalars on the right.

**Elaboration 1.** *What is a vierbein, really?* In a Minkowski spacetime, there is a *built-in* way of identifying neighbourhoods of any two points (think about it literally: a point and its neighbours). It is *consistent* in the sense that going from $A$ to $B$ and then from $B$ to $C$ is the same thing as going directly from $A$ to $C$. In most other situations, there is no such *natural* prescription, and general relativity exploits this fact in a useful way.

How do you *describe* such a prescription, though, natural or not? A useful (mathematical) worldview tells you to keep things *local* if you can, so you consider tangent vectors—intuitively, “infinitely small” displacements—instead of finite neighbourhoods. Denote the (vector space of) tangent vectors at point $x \in M$ by $T_xM$; then our problem is to describe a *consistent* identification $T_xM \leftrightarrow T_yM$ for $x\not= y$.

Choose a basis of tangent vectors at any point in spacetime, $\mathbf e_\alpha(x) \in T_xM, \alpha = 0,\ldots,3$, and you have an algorithm for moving vectors around: given a vector $\mathbf v \in T_xM$ at a point $x$, expand it in the local basis as $\mathbf v = v^\alpha\mathbf e_\alpha(x)$ and then use these coordinates to build a tangent vector at any other point: $v^\alpha\mathbf e_\alpha(y) \in T_yM$. Convince yourself that this prescription is *consistent*, and that any *reasonable* prescription can be described this way by choosing a basis at a single point and moving it to every other point. (What is *reasonable*?) To do physics, it is useful to limit ourselves to orthonormal (a.k.a. local inertial) frames with $\mathbf e_\alpha\cdot\mathbf e_\beta = \eta_{\alpha\beta}$.

**Elaboration 2.** *Where are the sixteen components?* Choose now a coordinate system on the spacetime, that is, an assignment to every<sup>1</sup> point $x$ of a set of four numbers $x^\mu, \mu = 0,\ldots,3$. There is then a distinguished set of tangent vectors at every point of spacetime, the *infinitesimal displacements along a particular coordinate* conventionally denoted by $\partial_\mu\equiv\partial_\mu(x)$. These vectors form a basis, but they are not necessarily orthonormal: indeed, $\partial_r(r,\phi)$ has length one in polar coordinates, but $\partial_\phi(r,\phi)$ has length $r$. Any *other* vierbein we might have had can now be expanded in these:
$$ \mathbf e_\alpha(x) = e^\mu_\alpha(x)\partial_\mu(x). $$
Here you go, *sixteen* scalars $(e^\mu_\alpha)$. Their dependence on $x$ reflects the fact that the two prescriptions we now have can be *different*. And the indices $\alpha$ and $\mu$ are of completely different nature, too: they label different sets of basis vectors, so (e. g.) contracting them is as geometrically meaningful as $v^x\partial_r$. However, you *can* package the sixteen functions $e^\mu_\alpha$ into four sets of four both as $(e_\alpha)^\mu$, like we have done originally, and as $(e^\mu)_\alpha$, like in your formula (how can this be useful?).

**Elaboration 3.** *What is a formula that does work?* For Dirac’s (ultimately misguided) attempt at relativistic quantum mechanics, not only do you want a first-order equation instead of the energy-momentum relation: you also need the (second-order) relation to *follow from* it. A good way to ensure something second-order and linear follows from something first-order and linear is to demand that the latter squared equals the former<sup>2</sup>. Let’s try *any* inhomogeneous first-order operator, calling its coefficients $\gamma^\mu$ and $\delta$:
$$
  \left(p_\mu\cdot\gamma^\mu \pm m\cdot\delta\right)\psi = 0.
$$

The thing in the parentheses is an *operator*, so squaring it means applying it two times. *You can’t multiply a scalar by a vector two times*, so your original method can’t work. You can, however, pretend that these symbols multiply in *some* reasonable<sup>3</sup> way and find out what that way must be so that $(\cdots)^2 = (p^2 - m^2)\cdot 1$. We need (although rarely write explicitly) the explicit $1$ in the last formula because we need to embed the *scalar* Klein-Gordon operator into the space those weird symbols live in. Work it out (you may assume $\delta = 1$ using the above definition of $1$) and you’ll get the [correct result](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_algebra). Take care to avoid any prejudices about the $\gamma$s.

<sup><sup>1</sup> I pretend we only need one chart for the sake of simplicity: every argument here is local, so there’s little use concerning ourselves with global issues.

<sup>2</sup> I don’t know if it’s the only one (modulo constant factors); edits welcome.

<sup>3</sup> Associative, distributive and commuting with numbers and differential operators.</sup>

Comment: +1 I really like your answer. I dont understand how this didnt get more upvotes... I hope to hear more from you on SE!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Now I get that what I was doing was a bit naive. And thanks for the explanation of vierbeins! Really instructive and helpful.

Comment: @Rafael Glad I could help! If you think this answer resolves your question *completely*, consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).